# PHP access value using case insensitive index

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

how to access a value in php array using case insensitive index.
like

```
$x = array('a'=>'ddd');
```

any function to access it using $x['A'];

Comment: $x = array(strtoupper('a')=>'ddd'); $y = $x[strtoupper('A')];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is just not the way strings / array work, in PHP.

In PHP, **`"a"` and `"A"` are two different strings**.

Array keys are either integers or strings.

So, `$a["a"]` and `$a["A"]` point to two distinct entries in the array.

You have two possible solutions :

- Either always using lower-case *(or upper-case)* keys -- which is probably the best solution.
- Or search through all the array for a possible matching key, each time you want to access an entry -- which is a bad solution, as you'll have to loop over *(in average)* half the array, instead of doing a fast access by key.

In the first case, you'll have to use [`strtolower()`](http://www.php.net/strtolower) each time you want to access an array-item :

```
$array[strtolower('KEY')] = 153;
echo $array[strtolower('KEY')];
```

In the second case, mabe something like this might work :

*(Well, this is a not-tested idea ; but it might serve you as a basis)*

```
if (isset($array['key'])) {
    // use the value -- found by key-access (fast)
}
else {
    // search for the key -- looping over the array (slow)
    foreach ($array as $upperKey => $value) {
        if (strtolower($upperKey) == 'key') {
            // You've found the correct key
            // => use the value
        }
    }
}
```

But, again it is a bad solution !

Comment: There is an extra "$" before the "as" in the loop. otherwise looks good!

Answer (score 4):

I would use OOP here, either extend ArrayObject or implement ArrayAcess and then in the offset methods use relevant string functions to match either case.

This is AFAIK the *only* way to be able to access it using `$x['A'];` syntax.

Of course I show no interest here in optimizing for speed. You should have to decide if speed or readable code is your primary goal.

Example:

```
class MyArray extends ArrayObject {
    public function offsetGet($index) {
        if ($this->offsetExists($index)) {
            return parent::offsetGet($index);
        }
        if ($this->offsetExists(strtolower($index))) {
            return parent::offsetGet(strtolower($index));
        }
        if ($this->offsetExists(strtoupper($index))) {
            return parent::offsetGet(strtoupper($index));
        }
        return null;
    }

}

$x = array('a'=>'ddd');
$x = new MyArray($x);
echo $x['A'];
```

Output:

```
ddd
```

Comment: I suppose someone didn't like my answer. I'd appreciate if someone could tell me what's wrong with it.

Comment: The idea being? My code, the reasoning behind it, or the original problem? If it is my code, what are the possible ways of improving it?

Answer (score 2):

```
function array_keys_to_lower($array)
{
  $lc_array = array();

  foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  {
    $lc_array[strtolower($key)] = $value;
  }

  return $lc_array;
}

function get_value($array, $index)
{
  $lc_array = array_keys_to_lower($array);

  return $lc_array[strtolower($index)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy.
Don't do it.

Obfuscating your own code is not a brilliant idea.
Just follow syntax rules and you'll be okay.

Comment: People in this thread should follow this advice. Calling `array_change_key_case` on anything causes long term problems on any code base as there's a need to add `strtolower` calls all over the place, and soon it starts creeping in unrelated parts of the codebase (which might not be case insensitive).

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own function for that, pseudocode:

```
function getElem(index, array){
  return array[toLower(index)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$index = "a";

$index = strtoupper($index);

$ret = $a[$index];
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess without changing your current array usage would be something like this:

```
$x = array('a'=>'ddd');

echo isset($x['a']) ? $x['a'] : $x['A'];
```

You could have this a function like following:

```
$x = array('a'=>'ddd');

echo getIndex($x, 'a');

// return either the value of $x['a'], $['A'] or null
function getIndex($array, $index) {
    return isset($x[strtolower($index)]) ? $x[strtolower($index)] : (isset($x[strtoupper($index)]) ? $x[strtoupper($index)] : null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late, but I think what you are trying to accomplish can be done easily:

```
$key = 'Key';
$array[$key] = 153;

$array = array_change_key_case($array)
echo $array[strtolower($key)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_change_key_case` to change the key case of your array, convert all keys to lower case or upper case and have your peace of mind.

example:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$headers = array_change_key_case($headers, CASE_UPPER);
    if (isset($headers['AUTHENTICATION'])) {
         // do your thing
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php