# Simple ajax script to display a book's name

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I started learning Ajax and I did this simple HTML page that displays a user input, when he types the name of a book (stored in an array in the php file), using ajax, the user can see below the input the results while he types, this is the part I couldn't manage to do, Here's the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bookstore.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body onload="process()">
  <h1>
    Hadhemi's BookStore !
  </h1>
  Enter the book you want to order
  <input type="text" id="userInput">
  <div id="underInput"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the JS file

```js
// 3 functions : create an object, communicate and response
var xmlHttp=createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() 
{
    var xmlHttp; 

    if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try 
        {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //check for IE
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            xmlHttp = false;
        } 
    }
    else 
    {
        try 
        {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // ! IE
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if (!xmlHttp) 
        alert("Can't Create that object");
    else
        return xmlHttp;
}

function process() 
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4) 
    {
        book = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET","book.php?book=" + book,true); 
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null); 
    }
    else 
    {
        setTimeout('process()',1000); 
    }
}

function handleServerResponse() 
{
    //sends back an xml file

    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4) 
    {
        if(xmlHttp.status==200) 
        {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement=xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data; 
            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML= message;
            setTimeout('process()',1000); 
        }

        else
        {
            alert("OOps! Something went wrong!");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the PHP file :

```
   <?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" enconding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo'<response>';

$book = $_GET['book'];
$bookArray = array('Book1','Book2','Book3');
if(in_array($book, $bookArray))
    echo 'We do have'.$book.'!';
elseif ($book='') 
    echo 'Enter a book name idiot!';
else
    echo 'We dont have'.$book.'!';

echo'</response>';

?>
```

I can't manage to display what the JS file is supposed to do, anyone knows how to fix it?

EDIT: I placed all the files in the www folder under Wamp.

Comment: Just a piece of advice , If your still in the learning process at the moment, It is better to use jquery. There is a jquery ajax which is much easier to use than this one.

Comment: `elseif ($book='')` you're assigning rather than comparing.

Comment: Yes I'm still in the learning process and thank you for your advice I will check jQuery.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I fixed that and still same problem, it's not displaying anything but the html.

Comment: keep in mind that `Book1` and `book1` are not the same in an array etc.. Update your question with the correct syntax you're using for the `elseif` in order to avoid further confusion. As for *"not displaying anything but the html"* - are you sure PHP is running and installed? You on a local machine or hosted?

Comment: Just a piece of advice, if you are still in the learning process, don't ever use any framework to learn a programming language, you will be abstracted away from what is happening and you will never learn the language properly. Get dirty and learn the proper way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things wrong in what you posted.

Firstly, you have a typo in:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" enconding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
                              ^ the "n"
```

Which should read as `encoding`.

Having errors set to be displayed on your server would have thrown you the following:

> XML Parsing Error: XML declaration not well-formed Location: http://www.example.com/book.php?book.php?book= Line Number 1, Column 21:

Plus, do keep in mind that, and as I stated in comments that `Book1` and `book1` are not treated the same, therefore the array keys are considered as case-sensitive.

Consult the following answer on Stack:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5404753/

You're also doing an assignment for while using a single equal sign:

```
elseif ($book='')
             ^
```

rather than a comparison, which should contain an additional equal sign:

```
elseif ($book=='')
             ^^
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Plus, make sure that PHP is indeed installed, running and properly configured.