# Modify form input value on submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I wasn't sure how to phrase the title, but here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a form to login to webmail, I don't have access to the webmail - it just posts the form input to the website and the webmail server takes it from there.

Everyone logging in to this page will be using the same email extension (e.g. "@myemail.com"), so I want to save the hassle of typing that every time, instead they can just write "mike" and the form will add "@myemail.com" on it's own.

I could post this form to a middle ground php page that sticks "mike" + "@mymail.com" together and posts this info to the webmail?

Or is there a simpler way to do this without having to create another page?

```
<form name="loginForm" action="http://webmail.emailsrvr.com/login.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="js_autodetect_results" value="SMPREF_JS_OFF">
<input type="hidden" name="just_logged_in" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="v3">
<input type="hidden" name="useSSL" id="useSSL" value="">

<input type="email" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>

<label for="remember"><input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember my info</label>
<button type="submit">Sign In</button>

</form>
```

I want to take the value entered here...

```
<input type="email" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
```

...and add an extension like "@myemail.com" to it, then post it.

Any idea? Thanks in advance for your help.

---

I could do something like this?

PAGE 1 - Enter username and password...

```
<input type="text" name="send_email" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
<input type="password" name="send_password" placeholder="Password" required>

<label for="remember"><input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember my info</label>
<button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

PAGE 2 - PHP takes username and adds "@myemail.com" and sends form...

```
<?php
    $form_email = $form_password = "";

    if (!empty($_POST['send_email']) && !empty($_POST['send_password'])) { 
        $form_email = $test($_POST['send_email']) . '@fountaincreations.ca';
        $form_password = $test($_POST['send_password']); 

        echo '<form name="loginForm" action="http://webmail.emailsrvr.com/login.php" method="POST" target="_blank">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="js_autodetect_results" value="SMPREF_JS_OFF">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="just_logged_in" value="1">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="v3">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="useSSL" id="useSSL" value="">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="' . $form_email . '">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="form_password" value="' . $form_password . '">';
        echo '</form>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p style="text-align:center;padding:40px 20px;">Please go back and try again.</p>';
    }

    function test($data) {
        $data = strtolower(data);
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

How do I tell PHP to automatically submit the form though?

---

Here's what I have if I were to use jQuery:

It doesn't currently work though.

HTML:

```
<div class="box top">
<form name="loginForm" action="http://webmail.emailsrvr.com/login.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="js_autodetect_results" value="SMPREF_JS_OFF">
<input type="hidden" name="just_logged_in" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="v3">
<input type="hidden" name="useSSL" id="useSSL" value="">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner-row"><input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus></div>
    <div class="inner-row"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required></div>
    <div class="inner-row">
        <div class="inner-col col-2-4"><label for="remember"><input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember my info</label></div>
        <div class="inner-col col-2-4"><button type="submit">Sign In</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="box bottom">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="inner-row"><p>Already signed in? <a href="http://webmail.emailsrvr.com/a/webmail.php" target="_blank"><b>Go to your inbox.</b></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button[type='submit']").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var userEmail = $.trim($("input[name='user_name']").val());
        $("input[name='user_name']").val(userEmail+"@fountaincreations.ca");
        $("form[name='loginForm']").submit();
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: basically you want to attach "@mymail.com" with input value on form submit?

Comment: so, why the jquery/php tags? what exactly are you looking for here; solutions for either or, or both?  if jQuery, where's your code for it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't know anything about jQuery, I know a little PHP - just added what I would do for PHP. I want either or, I just don't know what makes more sense

Comment: Personally Matthew, I'd use both (JS/PHP), if you're looking to incorporate a JS/jQuery solution. The fact that users can disable JS (I being one of those people who doesn't load JS by default), will render a JS method pointless. A *Plan-B* such as a serverside solution should be taken into consideration.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Fair enough, I don't always use JS myself, so that's why I'm not sure about it - I don't know the best practices for doing this sort of thing though - so myabe the best way to do it is with JS. I'm more familar with PHP though.

Comment: There is something that you need to be aware of, and that is; anyone visiting your page and entering/guessing a name, stands at spamming your site, and sending emails to you that may not have come from the actual users themselves. I would rethink this and possibly use a database instead, where they need to login in order to be able to use their username to send you an email. Or, an `.htaccess` file with a username/password `.htpasswd` file.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that's all taken care of, the form takes them to an external page where everything is checked before anything can happen, I just don't have access to that external page.

Comment: Ah, good stuff. Well Matthew, if the answer given below didn't solve the question, and from what I see in the actual question being *"How do I tell PHP to automatically submit the form though?"*, you would need to use Ajax for that. As for "to automatically send it", is a bit unclear as to "how" exactly that should happen. As in "if this user exists while typing a name in the input, fetch it and if it does exist, send..."? If so, you would need to use an event listener.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I appreciate your input, is there any way you could show me an example of how I could do that? Or shoot me in the right direction any way? There must be a way to post a form with php if some result returns true?

Comment: You're welcome Matthew. Actually, I did place an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32343553/1415724 in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/32343310/ which will basically do what you're looking to do. The line `$bookArray = array('Book1','Book2','Book3');` already contains an array of allowed searches, so you just need to replace those with ones that you may already be using. You will need to do a few modifications though, since I don't know how you're getting your present information from. If you feel that answer helps, feel free to upvote it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to attach username + "@mymail.com" to useremail field, here is my suggestion:
1# create input user_email (just hide this field)

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_email" id="user_email" placeholder="User Email">
```

2# add js below

```
$('#user_name').on('input', function() {
   username = this.value+'@myemail.com';
   $('#user_email').val(username);
});
```

[here example](https://jsfiddle.net/rifadayyan/ja585yva/)

Comment: Actually this is a really smart JS work around! I'm going to try implementing it now

Comment: This ends up being less code in the end! Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will go like this, hope this will help you. What i am doing in this code is, first I stop the form from being submitted through `e.preventDefault();` and then i am taking the value of the required input and assigning it back value by attaching "@mymail.com".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button[type='submit']").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var userEmail = $.trim($("input[type='email']").val());
        $("input[type='email']").val(userEmail+"@mymail.com");
        $("form[name='loginForm']").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: For JS, this is fine. However, if a user has it disabled, then the OP will need to look for a backup solution.

Comment: @Fred-ii- and that's what I'm thinking so far, I'm unsure about jQuery

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening but this isn't working?

Comment: Just updated the question with what I have including your code that doesn't work.